# Unable to use select top N shortcut on Azure SQL Database via SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, azure-sql-database

Yesterday morning I was able to query my Azure databases via SSMS and the `Select Top N` menu shortcut. That afternoon I received a couple of alerts that my web applications couldn't connect to the database.

As a quick check to verify if only that database was down or if all databases on that server were down I connected to the server via SSMS. I was able to view the schema/meta data present in the Object Viewer pane without any problems. I can also execute `SELECT` statements against the database when I write the query and/or execute a script. However, when I try to right click a table and use the `Select Top 1000 Rows' shortcut I get an error dialog box with the following message:

> Cannot read property IsMemoryOptimized. This property is not available on Windows Azure SQL Database.
>   (Microsoft.AqlServer.Smo)

Today I just noticed that my Azure SQL Database was inexplicably updated from V11 to V12. If this update happened yesterday afternoon that would be the only potential difference in configuration that I am aware of.

1. What can I do to suppress this error?
2. Why does a `Select top N` shortcut care about the `IsMemoryOptimized` property?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but Grant Fritchey posted about a similar form of this issue back in April of last year. - http://www.scarydba.com/2015/04/07/error-unknown-property-ismemoryoptimized/  .  It may not help you, but it may give you a different direction to look.

Comment: @mskinner That looks promising... Per the help menu my SSMS is version 12.0.4213.0 Which doesn't seem to match a SQL Server 2014 build https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2936603

Comment: @mskinner I just updated to the latest version 13.0.900.73 (2016 CTP3) and it is worse. Now I can't even view the list of tables.....

Comment: Well, that stinks!

Comment: @mskinner Agreed. I submitted a [connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2269216) about the 2016 CTP3 issue.